# I need clarificatio of sendDirect() method in OMNET

Tags: omnet++

Code below is from `OMNeT++` manual. My question is: do I use this method only when I am sending message from compound module to submodules?
If I can use this for communication between modules (`simpleModule A` sends `msg` to compound `moduleB` -> submodule B1) then isn't this violation of rules that communication must comply on the same level of hierarchy?

This is example code:

```
cModule *targetModule = getParentModule()->getSubmodule("node2");
sendDirect(new cMessage("msg"), targetModule, "in");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Usually communication between simple modules inside a compound module doesn't require `sendDirect()`. This kind of communication predominantly uses [`IdealChannel`](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:channels-overview) - i.e. a standard `OMNeT++` channel with no errors, zero delay and infinite bandwidth.